# Can I combine these two list comprehensions?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Here're two list comprehensions I'm working on:

```
basis_result = [[1 if value == '0' else -1 for value in sublist] for sublist in basis_result]
miti_basis_result = [[1 if value == '0' else -1 for value in sublist] for sublist in miti_basis_result]
```

They're only differed by the last part. I wonder how can I combine those list comprehensions? I was trying a shorter example: `aa,bb,cc = [i for i in [range(2),range(3),range(4)]]` but this method doesn't work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `[i for i in list]` is the same as `list`

Comment: @Nolan it's the same as `list.copy()` or `list[:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this.

```
basis_result, miti_basis_result = [[[1 if value == '0' else -1 for value in sublist] for sublist in result] for result in [basis_result, miti_basis_result]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can extract the common code as a function:

```
def process_result(result):
    return [
        [1 if value == '0' else -1 for value in sublist] 
        for sublist in result
    ]

basis_result = process_result(basis_result)
miti_basis_result = process_result(miti_basis_result)
```

If you want to handle all at once:

```
results = [process_result(r) for r in results]
```